# Understanding the sequence $ 1\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C} \to \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C^*} \to 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I want to understand this classic example of sheaves sequence

$$ 1\to \mathbb{Z}\to  \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C} \to  \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C^*} \to 1$$

$ \cdot \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C}$ is the sheaf of the holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$

$\cdot \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C^*} $ is the sheaf of the holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$

I can understand   that exp function gives us $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C} \to  \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C^*}$.

The questions I have regarding the sequence are:

What is $1$ stands for ? And how we can get  $ 1\to \mathbb{Z}$,
$\mathbb{Z}\to  \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C^*} \to 1$ ?

Why this sequence is important ? What information we get from this ?

Comment: $1$ is the trivial group. Another (maybe more standard) way to write the sequence is $0\to\mathbb Z\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb C}\to\mathcal O^\times_{\mathbb C}\to 1$.

Comment: You probably want $\mathcal O^\times_{\mathbb C}$, the sheaf of nowhere vanishing holomorphic functions, rather than $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^\times}$, the sheaf of functions on $\mathbb C^\times$

Comment: By the way, there is an analogous exact sequence for any complex manifold $X$. That can be used to relate the sheaf cohomology of $\mathbb Z$ (which is just singular cohomology) and the sheaf cohomology of $\mathcal O_X$.

Comment: Essentially, this sequence is saying that the exponential map is periodic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kenta S points out in the comments, the sequence might be better written as
$$
0 \to \underline{\Bbb{Z}} \to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}} \to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}}^*\to 0
$$
where the map $0\to \underline{\Bbb{Z}}$ is the inclusion of $0$ as the constant function $0(z) = 0$. Also note that $\underline{\Bbb{Z}}$ denotes the constant sheaf with values in $\Bbb{Z}$. Over a connected open set $U$,
$$\underline{\Bbb{Z}}(U) = \{f:U\to \Bbb{C}: f(z) = n\in \Bbb{Z} \:\text{for all}\: z\in U\}.$$
Viewing a constant function as a holomorphic function gives a natural inclusion $\underline{\Bbb{Z}}\to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}}$. The map $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{C}}^*\to 0$ is the map sending every function to $0$. Such a map always exists. In what follows, I will replace $\Bbb{C}$ by an arbitrary complex manifold $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, which is essentially a choice of a topological space with a sheaf of functions valued in $\Bbb{C}$ called "holomorphic" (although the existence of such a structure is a rather special situation). For concreteness, you could just take $X = \Bbb{C}$, although this sequence will be more useful in cases such as $X$ being a Riemann surface. Associated to a short exact sequence of sheaves
$$
0\to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}\to \mathcal{H}\to 0
$$
is a long exact sequence of sheaf cohomology groups:
$$
0\to H^0(X,\mathcal{F})\to H^0(X,\mathcal{G})\to H^0(X,\mathcal{H})\to H^1(X,\mathcal{F})\to \cdots\to H^n(X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^n(X,\mathcal{G})\to H^n(X,\mathcal{H})\to 0.
$$
Here, $n$ is the dimension of $X$. In this particular case, the short exact sequence relates three very important series of sheaf cohomologies. It turns out that $H^i(X,\underline{\Bbb{Z}}) = H^i_{\mathrm{sing}}(X;\Bbb{Z})$, the singular cohomology of $X$. These groups are pieces of topological data. On the other hand, $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ packages information about the complex structure on $X$, as does $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)$. Notably, $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*) \cong \mathrm{Pic}(X)$, which is the group of holomorphic line bundles on $X$. These are important when defining embeddings of (compact) manifolds into projective spaces. Anyway, to see this principle in action we can write out the first few rounds of the sequence:
$$
0\to H^0(X,\Bbb{Z})\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)\to H^1(X,\Bbb{Z}) \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to \mathrm{Pic}(X)\to H^2(X,\Bbb{Z})\to\cdots
$$
The map $\mathrm{Pic}(X)\to H^2(X,\Bbb{Z})$ gives a way to define the first Chern class map, $c_1:\mathrm{Pic}(X)\to H^2(X,\Bbb{Z})$ which is important in the theory of characteristic classes (and in many other places including intersection thory).

In one line: this sequence relates the complex structure of the space $X$ to the topological invariants of the underlying topological space $X$.

Comment: IMO This is already an excellent answer, but for the OP in particular, it might be helpful to explain some consequences in a particular case e.g. what happens when $X=\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$.